# Just installed Ubuntu Server 20.04 on a tablet (Teknio EL2IN1-1102T) without an ethernet connector. Netplan isn't connecting to wifi

Tags: networking, server, wireless

It's a Teknio EL2IN1-1102T. Followed the green check mark answer in [this thread](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/111722/rpi-4-running-ubuntu-server-20-04-cant-connect-to-wifi) and still nothing. `ip a` shows `lo` and `wlan0`, and wlan0 shows no IP(v4) address.

```
$ lspci -knn | grep Net -A3
<no output>

$ cat /etc/network/interfaces
<no output>

$ cat /etc/netplan/*.yaml
# This is the network config written by 'subiquity'
network:
    version: 2

$ sudo lshw -C network
*-network DISABLED
    description: Wireless interface
    physical id: 1
    logical name: wlan0
    serial: a0:2c:36:ba:76:9c
    capabilities: ethernet physical wireless
    configuration: broadcast=yes driver=rtl8723bs multicast=yes wireless=unassociated
```

---

```
$ cat /etc/netplan/*.yaml
# This is the network config written by 'subiquity'
network:
    version: 2
    renderer: networkd
        wifis:
            wlan0:
                dhcp4: yes
                access-points:
                    "myaccesspoint":
                        password: "password"

$ sudo netplan --debug generate
** (generate:1292): DEBUG: 17:20:07.965: Processing input file /etc/netplan/00-installer-config.yaml..
** (generate:1292): DEBUG: 17:20:10.170: starting new processing pass
** (generate:1292): DEBUG: 17:20:10.171: wlan0: adding wifi AP 'MikroTik-4t0n10'
** (generate:1292): DEBUG: 17:20:10.171: We have some netdefs, pass them through a final round of validation
** (generate:1292): DEBUG: 17:20:10.171: wlan0: setting default backend to 1
** (generate:1292): DEBUG: 17:20:10.171: Configuration is valid
** (generate:1292): DEBUG: 17:20:10.173: Generating output files..
** (generate:1292): DEBUG: 17:20:10.173: Creating wpa_supplicant config
** (generate:1292): DEBUG: 17:20:10.173: wlan0: Creating wpa_supplicant configuration file run/netplan/wpa-wlan0.conf
** (generate:1292): DEBUG: 17:20:10.174: Creating wpa_supplicant unit /run/systemd/system/netplan-wpa-wlan0.service
   (generate:1292): GLib-DEBUG: 17:20:10.174: posix_spawn avoided (workdir specified) (fd close requested)
** (generate:1292): DEBUG: 17:20:10.197: Creating wpa_supplicant service enablement link /run/systemd/system/systemd-networkd.service.wants/netplan-wpa-wlan0.service
** (generate:1292): DEBUG: 17:20:10.198: NetworkManager: definition wlan0 is not for us (backend 1)
   (generate:1292): GLib-DEBUG: 17:20:10.199: posix_spawn avoided (fd close requested)

$ sudo lshw -C network

  *-network
   description: Wireless interface
   physical id: 1
   logical name: wlan0
   serial: a0:2c:36:ba:76:9c
   capabilities: ethernet physical wireless
   configuration: broadcast=yes driver=rtl8723bs multicast=yes wireless=unassociated
```

---

```
# cat *.yaml:

# This is the network config written by 'subiquity'
network:
  version: 2
  renderer: networkd
  wifis:
    wlan0:
      dhcp4: yes
      access-points:
        "SSID":
          password: "password"
```

---

```
# lshw -C network
  *-network DISABLED
       description: Wireless interface
       physical id: 1
       logical name: wlan0
       serial: 00:e0:4c:b7:23:00
       capabilities: ethernet physical wireless
       configuration: broadcast=yes driver=rtl8723bs multicast=yes wireless=unassociated
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Create `/etc/cloud/cloud.cfg.d/99-disable-network-config.cfg` with the following:

```
network: {config: disabled}
```

Edit your `/etc/netplan/*.yaml` file to look exactly like this... same spacing, same indentation, no tabs... fill in the network name and password...

```
network:
  version: 2
  renderer: networkd
  wifis:
    wlan0:
      dhcp4: true
      access-points:
        "network_ssid_name":
          password: "**********"
```

`sudo netplan generate`

`sudo netplan apply`

`reboot`

**Note**: If this tablet is mobile, **Ubuntu Desktop** might be a better choice.

**Update #1:**

Install `wpasupplicant` this way...

`sudo apt-get update`

`sudo apt-get install wpasupplicant`

`reboot`

Then it should work.

**Update #2:**

Go to https://packages.ubuntu.com/search?keywords=wpasupplicant&searchon=names&suite=focal&section=all and download the wpasupplicant to your USB drive, then install it with `sudo apt install /path_to/filename.deb` or `sudo dpkg -i /path_to/filename.deb`.

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/111648/discussion-on-answer-by-heynnema-just-installed-ubuntu-server-20-04-on-a-tablet).